# time series similarity heuristic

Tags: statistics, time-series

What is a good heuristic for time series similarity. I'm ok with false positives bc I will then pass the results of the heuristic to an actual series similarity algo. Basically I want the heuristic to (1) be fast AND (2) to filter bad series before the more extensive time series similarity algo is applied to the most probable matching time series.

I've tried Pearson probabilities, Pearson on CUSUM of time series, Kendall probability, Kruskal probability and a few other models. Pearson gives the best results so far.

A problem I have with Pearson probability is that if 1 series is shifted it will not be able to tell that the time series match, so it eliminates some good matches.

I would be ok with using 2 or more FAST heuristics where each one is good at specific cases like say good at finding shifted time series similarities and one good at finding non shifted time series similarities.

This SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723157/how-to-compare-two-curves-arrays-of-points suggests using Sum of squares.

Any ideas on what heuristic to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps for each pair you want to compare, you can adjust for shift and scale then apply the different methods you mentioned. Specifically,

1. Lets say we want to compare a given pair of time series $T_1,T_2$,
2. Let $\sigma$ be a scale factor and $\tau$ be a shift term.
3. Select an goodness of fit metric between two time series $\theta(T_1,T_2)$ (e.g., LSE, MAD),
4. Find $(\tau^*,\sigma^*):= \min\limits_{\tau,\sigma} \theta(\sigma T_1+\tau,T_2)$
5. Perform a test of correlation. I would have thought that a non-parametric method would be better, but you may find the Pearson method is the best. This will be an empirical exercise, so I can't prescribe anything here.

All of the above can be automated, and each step does not involve a computationally intense algorithm. This might meet your needs.

Comment: I'd like to check out MAD and LSE; could you expand what those stand for.

Comment: @Adrian : Sure. Let $f$ and $g$ be two time series, with respective values $f_i,g_i$. Then the Mean Absolute Deviation (MAD) is $\frac{1}{N}\sum |f_i-g_i|$ and the LSE is the least squares estimator, which we can turn into the Mean Squared Error (MSE): $\frac{1}{N}\sum (f_i-g_i)^2$. In general, you can let $\theta=\frac{1}{N}\sum(f_i-g_i)^k, k>0$. The larger $k$ is, the more you penalize large deviations at the expense of ignoring small-scale deviations.

Comment: I've noticed that MSE works really well on non normalized time series. As soon as I normalize them it says everything matches. By normalizing I mean subtracting the mean and dividing by standard deviation.

Comment: @Adrian that's good to hear (I'm guessing?). Sounds like your time series are quite similar to each other, apart from shifts and scaling. To the extent that those do not matter, then it sounds like it should be what you are looking for....have you tried finding a series that does NOT come out similar (just so you can see what one would look like?

Comment: Good idea! I just don't know any methods - will Google. For similarity I look only at the shape of the series not magnitude. BTW I just tried doing MSE after doing CUSUM on the normalized series and this works pretty well too.

Comment: @Adrian since you are focused on shape, one way to generate "distorted" time series is to multiply your shifted/scaled time series by a nonlinear function $g(z)$ (e.g., $z^2$), so that you have $[g(z)(\sigma T_1+\tau),T_2]$ as your two time series being compared. The larger the value of $z$ the more nonlinearity should be present. At some point, the first time series will be so distorted that no value for the shift and scale will "correct" it to the point of being similar to the second time series.